# How to open a .txt file and display it in a text box using Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am using [Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_Basic_Express), and this is very new to me. I have a browse button, and I added code in such a way that a file is browsed and its path is displayed in a label box when I click the browse button.

Similarly I want the content of the file I select to be displayed in text box. I use the following code:

```
    Imports System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim oReader As StreamReader

    OpenFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True
    OpenFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = True
    OpenFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = False

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        oReader = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, True)
        RichTextBox1.Text = oReader.ReadToEnd
    End If
```

But I got syntax a error for the `Imports` line and [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as undeclared. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your import statement should be at the very top of the file, outside of a Sub or Function, and your oReader declaration should be at least inside the class, or inside a method.

Additionally, your import is not right. "Imports System.IO.StreamReader" should be "Imports System.IO", otherwise you will only have access to the classes declared within StreamReader (if there are any). What you really want is to import the System.IO namespace so that you have access to the types declared in that namespace.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class MyForm

    ' ... Whatever code you have for your form

    Public Sub OpenFile()

        Dim oReader As StreamReader

        OpenFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True
        OpenFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = True
        OpenFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"
        OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
        OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = False

        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            oReader = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, True)
            RichTextBox1.Text = oReader.ReadToEnd
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be importing `System.IO` namespace.

And see these changes in the code:

```
Dim oReader As StreamReader
openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True
openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = True
openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"
openFileDialog1.FileName = ""
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = False
If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    oReader = New StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName, True)
    richTextBox1.Text = oReader.ReadToEnd()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple use below code that will help you

Open file code

```
  If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.RichTextBox1.LoadFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)

 End If
```

Save code

```
 If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

    RichTextBox1.SaveFile(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim reader As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\\testfile.txt")

    Dim a As String
    Dim B As String
    Do
        a = reader.ReadLine

        For i = 0 To a.Length

            If a.Substring(i, 1).ToString() = "{" Then

                B = B & a.Substring(i)

                LBL.Text = B
            End If
          'Iam Juman Mandra
        Next
    Loop Until a Is Nothing

    reader.Close()
```